# Fail2ban failed to start on Centos 7. Missing /var/log/secure file

Tags: ssh, centos, iptables, vps, fail2ban

A few days ago I bought vps and installed Centos 7 on it. Now I'm trying to set up fail2ban for ssh. I installed epel-release. Iptables was in use by default. This is what I'm getting when I'm trying to start fail2ban:

```
 Job for fail2ban.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status fail2ban.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Debug of fail2ban start :

```
[root@server ~]# /usr/bin/fail2ban-client -v -v start
INFO   Loading configs for fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading configs for fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
INFO   Using socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
INFO   Loading configs for jail under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading configs for jail under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf,/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf, /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-fedora.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-common.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-overrides.local']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/paths-common.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/paths-fedora.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/jail.local']
INFO   Loading configs for filter.d/sshd under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading configs for filter.d/sshd under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.local']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/common.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf']
INFO   Loading configs for action.d/iptables-multiport under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading configs for action.d/iptables-multiport under /etc/fail2ban
DEBUG  Reading config files: /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-common.conf']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-blocktype.local']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-common.local']
INFO     Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-common.conf', '/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf']
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/secure
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for sshd jail
```

I tried to reinstall iptables, but still after fresh installation I'm missing secure log file. It may be cause by vps provider settings?

Comment: this appears to be related to an reported bug: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1372 some of the solutions on the report may work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the missing file?

```
touch /var/log/secure
chown root. /var/log/secure
chmod 0600 /var/log/secure
```

Then:

```
systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

---

`/var/log/secure` comes from `rsyslog`.  Make sure you have `authpriv.* /var/log/secure` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `rsyslog` is running:

```
systemctl status rsyslog
```

Comment: I've been missing rsyslog package. I thought it's installed by default. Anyway, thanks for help.